# send messages to facebook friends in iPhone, Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

i am creating one app, in which i have to included message section to send messages to friends via their email id. and i have to add facebook option to send message to users facebook friends. can any one help me how to solved dis prob... i am research on this for last 2 days.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to integrate facebook sdk

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/

Comment: thank you, i know that if we use facebook in our app we need do install/add facebook sdk in our app. i need to send messages from this facebook account's friend list either one or more friend.

Answer (score 0):

You cant Post to friends wall from now...

Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API 
We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.